# How can I determine how many squares are needed to fill a browser window, dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making colored squares to fill a browser window (say, 20px by 20px repeated horizontally and vertically).

There are 100 different colors, each link to a different link (blog post relevant to that color).

I want to fill the browser window with at least 1 of each colored square, and then repeat as necessary to fill the window, so that there are colored squares on the whole background, as the user drags the window smaller and larger.

If these were just images, setting a repeatable background would work. But, I would like them to be links. I'm not sure where to start on this. Any ideas, tips?

Here's the link to the site I'm working on: http://spakonacompany.com/

I think the most specific piece I need here is this: how can I determine the number of squares needed to repeat to fill the background, using jQuery that dynamically calculates that using the size of the browser window, including when dragged, resized, etc?

Many thanks. :)

Comment: You can't link a background so this is going to take a little work to get done. Do the links have a pattern that you can iterate through with a loop? If so, then you could use some css and jquery to create all of the images with links as the very first elements on the page so everything else below can be positioned on top of those images.

Comment: Why the downvote? Question sounds appropriate to me.

Comment: You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/47hBs/. The color are randomly picked here, but you could iterate through an array and assign colors, or classes, to the links.

Comment: Thanks Brent. Definitely on listing the links first, and positioning these behind the main site. The links don't have a pattern (they're WordPress blog post links) - I thought I'd repeat them with jQuery. @j08691 - something like this, although how can I determine how many squares need to be used? something involving calculations of the browser window size?

Comment: To whoever downvoted me: just added some more information, hopefully that makes it more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: You could do that, but then you'd have to recalc it on resize, or just generate a large number.

Comment: A large number causes the page to scroll, though - it doesn't behave like a background that would just get cut off to the browser's size. Ideas?

Comment: If you set the overflow to hidden you should see no scroll.

Comment: Perfect, I hadn't thought about applying that to a body. Thank you! :) Getting closer! :)

Comment: Which browsers are you planning to support?

Comment: How are you storing the colors? Do you have a predetermined list or is it 100 random ones?

Comment: The colors are WordPress posts that are tagged with a hex value. I said 100 colors just to be general, but it's really 107 (and will probably increase, consider it a dynamic number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get browser's window width and height I use this function ->

```
//checking if the browser is Internet Explorer    
var isIEX = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/);

var doc = isIEX ? document.documentElement : document.body;

function getwWH() {

var wD_ = window;

innerW = wD_.innerWidth || doc.clientWidth;
innerH = wD_.innerHeight || doc.clientHeight;

return {iW:innerW, iH:innerH}

}
```

There is also a native method of detecting when the browser's window is being resized which works in all major browsers (including IE 8, if you're planning on supporting it) ->

```
window.onresize = function(){ 

//here goes the code whenever the window is getting resized

}
```

So, in order to define how many squares are required to fill the window, you can get the window's width and divide it by the width of the square you are going to fill the window with ->

//getting total number of squares for filling the width and the height

```
width_ = getwWH().iW; //the width of the window

height_ = getwWH().iH; //the height of the window
```

If your square's width and height are static 20 by 20, than we can calculate total number of squares per window by dividing our **width_** variable by 20 (the same for the **height_**) ->

```
squaresPerWidth = width_/20;
squaresPerHeight = height_/20;
```

So every time our browser window is getting resized we do this ->

```
window.onresize = function(){

    width_ = getwWH().iW;
    height_ = getwWH().iH;

    squaresPerWidth = width_/20;
    squaresPerHeight = height_/20;

    //and the rest of the code goes here

}
```

Haven't tested it but this should work.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I need, thank you! I'll be back to accept answers after I try these. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I whipped up.  It uses a fixed number of resizable squares, but if you need squares of a fixed size, you just set the window to `overflow: hidden` and generate an unreasonably large number of squares.

```
var fillGrid = function(getColor, onClick) {
  var tenTimes = function(f){
    return $.map(new Array(10),
                 function(n, i) {
                   return f(i);
                 });
  };

  var DIV = function() {
    return $('<div></div>');
  };

  var appendAll = function(d, all) {
    $.map(all, function(e)  {
      d.append(e);
    });
    return d;
  };

  appendAll($('body'),
            tenTimes(function(col) {
              return appendAll(DIV().css({ height : "10%" }),
                               tenTimes(function(row) {
                                 return DIV().css({
                                   height : "100%",
                                   width : "10%",
                                   backgroundColor: getColor(row, col),
                                   'float' : "left"
                                 }).click(function() { onClick(row, col); });
                               }));
            }));
};
```

You have to supply two functions, one to specify the color, the other to be invoked when the user clicks.

Comment: Ah, cool! I like the idea of squares that size, there's no reason the squares need to be a certain size. Thank you! :)